# Class library using Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, class-library

I have two ASP.NET MVC5 projects, I want to connect them to the same database. I created a class library that contains the models and the `DbContext`.

The first app connects correctly, but when I run the second one I get an error says :

> Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\saibi\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MonPFE\MonPFE.Frontend\App_Data\MonPFEContext-20161121115318.mdf' as database 'MonPFEContext-20161121115318'

PS: I have `web.config` in each project.

Comment: It seem that latter project is using local database instead of the database the former one using. I believe you want to update database connection strings point to same database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the same connection string in each Web.config and that they point to the same database. Beware that relative paths for `AttachDbFilename` will point at different directories.

I'm betting you have Connection Strings that look something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MonPFEContext" connectionString=".\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MonPFEContext.mdf; Database=MonPFEContext;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

`|DataDirectory|` will typically be the `App_Data` folder in each web project. The database file exists in one web application, but not the other. Update `AttachDbFilename` to point to a full file path, or use a relative path to the same file.

Comment: I didn't get attention to the database path, Thanks @akatakritos it works now.